# Is it possible to check is loaded language files correctly with WordPress plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, translation, language

I have a plugin to be translated. I have done following tasks:

1. Loaded the TextDomain

```
$my_td = 'mysignup';
function my_signup_textdomain_init() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( $my_td, false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_signup_textdomain_init');
```

2. Added language files(po, pot, mo) in `wp_plugin_folder\my_signup\languages` (for Bengali bn_BD)

- mysignup.pot
- mysignup.mo
- bn_BD.po
- bn_BD.mo

3. Changed the language code in `wp_config.php` file

```
define('WPLANG', 'bn_BD');
```

But the problem is nothing is changed. I am not sure what I have done wrong.
Now I need to know how can I test everything, whether what I've done is fine, and how can I solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried [Debug Translations](http://marketpress.com/product/debug-translations/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my mistakes! I done everything good except 1 thing, textdomain setup.

I forgot that i have set the `$my_td` variable outside of function. For this reason, my textdomain was missing. So i made the variable **global** as following:

```
$my_td = 'mysignup';
function my_signup_textdomain_init() {
    global $my_td;
    load_plugin_textdomain( $my_td, false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_signup_textdomain_init');
```

Anyway thank for trying to help me.

> **Note: `mysignup-bn_BD.mo` or `mysignup.mo` both will work. But mysignup-bn_BD.mo is dynamic way.

Answer (score 2):

For plugins using the directory referred to by load_plugin_textdomain, the language files should be named "domain-locale.mo".

So for your case, the filenames should be `mysignup-bn_BD.mo`.

Comment: thanks. you are slightly right. But i have done another mistake.